# LINQ - append MemberBinding expression into exist MemberInit expression

Tags: c#, linq

Basic idea is similar to [Merging Expression Trees to Reuse in Linq Queries](http://coding.abel.nu/2013/01/merging-expression-trees-to-reuse-in-linq-queries/).

In my situation, I have two models and DTOs:

```
public class User
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public Extra Extra { get; set; }
}
public class Extra
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Text { get; set; }
}
public class UserDto
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public ExtraDto Extra { get; set; }
}
public class ExtraDto
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

and expressions:

```
Expression<Func<Extra, ExtraDto>> extraSelector = o => new ExtraDto
{
  Id = o.Id,
  Text = o.Text
};
Expression<Func<User, UserDto>> userSelector = o => new UserDto
{
  Id = o.Id,
  Name = o.Name
};
```

Now, I'd like to 'append' `extraSelector` into `userSelector`. The pseudo code is like:

```
var selectorExpression = userSelector.Append(user => user.Extra, extraSelector);
Context.Users.Select(selectorExpression).ToList();
```

The final expression would be like this:

```
Expression<Func<User, UserDto>> userSelector = o => new UserDto
{
  Id = o.Id,
  Name = o.Name,
  Extra = new ExtraDto
  {
    Id = o.Extra.Id,
    Text = o.Extra.Text
  }
};
```

I've tried using `ExpressionVisitor`, but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from the "merge" of the two selectors, you have to insert the "path" `o => o.Extra` into the `extraSelector` and create a new "bind expression" for the property `Extra` of `UserDto`.

In fact, i'm playing around with such scenarios within [this project](https://github.com/axelheer/nein-linq), where i've tried to abstract this kind of expression plumbing. Your "merge" would then look like that:

```
userSelector = extraSelector.Translate()
                            .Cross<User>(o => o.Extra)
                            .Apply(o => o.Extra, userSelector);
```

The `Translate` extension method is just a little helper to make use of type inference, `Cross` inserts `o => o.Extra` into the `extraSelector`, `Apply` creates the "bind expression" for the property `Extra` of `UserDto` and finally merges the result with `userSelector`.

Comment: Great project! I implemented something like 'selector reusing', but this project is way better than mine. Thanks.